# How to enter to the bootloader (DFU mode) in software on the STWIN

Tags: stm32, bootloader, dfu

Is there a way to jump to the bootloader from the application code on the STWIN ?(https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/steval-stwinkt1.html)

The following thread discusses the issue ([How do you jump to the bootloader (DFU mode) in software on the STM32 F072?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288453/how-do-you-jump-to-the-bootloader-dfu-mode-in-software-on-the-stm32-f072)) but for another board, so it is not applicable in my case.

PS:
I'am using Algobuilder to generate the firmware.

Answer (score 3):

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66538837/5872574) on the same topic shows a [nice solution](https://github.com/markusgritsch/SilF4ware/blob/94bb679119a0b9879fedc62a5e22f40623433242/SilF4ware/drv_reset.c) for another STM32L4 variant, which origiated in this [tutorial](https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2017/04/tutorial-jump-system-memory-software-stm32/). The [STWIN](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/steval-stwinkt1.html) is based on an [STM32L4R9](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32l4r9zi.html), but that interesting `jump_to_bootloader()` function might work similarly on an STWIN device. In application note [AN2606](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/b9/9b/16/3a/12/1e/40/0c/CD00167594.pdf/files/CD00167594.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00167594.pdf) in *Table 141. STM32L4Rxxx/4Sxxx* it can be verified that the bootloader firmware also starts at address 0x1FFF0000. (By the way: it also works without modification on the STM32F4Discovery board.)